# BigQuery Java API - Cannot Send Null For TableRow Value

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to set values on BigQuery table using java big query api but its throwing NullPointerException (`java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: popup=null` ) every time I send the null value.

The null value should be completely acceptable since my Mode is NULLABLE on schema itself. I have bunch of other fields that have null value on them.

Any suggestion on this issue would be really helpful for me, I am stuck no where due to this.

Note : I may ignore and not set those fields having null values on them but that is not the solution I am looking for. My piece of code is below:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
                row.set("ip", "test");
                row.set("popup", null);
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't explicitly set the value to `null`. Simply ignore it. If it's not present in the payload to BigQuery, it will be set to `null`. You will not be able to set it to `null` anyway, because the API is checking for `null` parameters, and you can't change that behaviour.

So, do this instead:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
row.set("ip", "test");
```